# Emotion detection in text using EmoRoberta

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I'm using Emoroberta for emotion detection and I want the output to be all emotions, each with its assigned score and not only the final emotion and its score. How can I do that?
This is the code I'm using:

```py
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("arpanghoshal/EmoRoBERTa")
model = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("arpanghoshal/EmoRoBERTa")
emotion = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model='arpanghoshal/EmoRoBERTa')
def get_emotion_label(text):
  return(emotion(text)[0]['label'])

df['Text']= df['Text'].apply(remove_html).apply(remove_URL).apply(remove_stopwords)
df['Emotion']= df['Text'].apply(get_emotion_label)
```

Comment: What's the output of `emotion(text)`? Does that contain all emotions?

Comment: No, this is the output for emotion("Thanks for using it.") : 
[{'label': 'gratitude', 'score': 0.9964383244514465}]

Comment: What's the output of `emotion(text, return_dict=True)`?

Comment: An Error:  TypeError: _batch_encode_plus() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_dict'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution is to add a parameter in the pipeline for it to become:

```
emotion = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model='arpanghoshal/EmoRoBERTa' , return_all_scores= True)
```

Answer (score 0):

once I get all the emotions out. Is there a way to sort them by scores in descending order? Or getting the top 5 emotions with the descending scores?

```
[[{'label': 'admiration', 'score': 0.0005006285500712693},
  {'label': 'amusement', 'score': 0.0002929244365077466},
  {'label': 'anger', 'score': 0.00023640353174414486},
  {'label': 'annoyance', 'score': 0.0012106695212423801},
  {'label': 'approval', 'score': 0.0062308544293046},
  {'label': 'caring', 'score': 0.001638480112887919},
  {'label': 'confusion', 'score': 0.0012553866254165769},
  {'label': 'curiosity', 'score': 0.0015351950423792005},
  {'label': 'desire', 'score': 8.997381519293413e-05},
  {'label': 'disappointment', 'score': 0.1479707956314087},
  {'label': 'disapproval', 'score': 0.01166599616408348},
  {'label': 'disgust', 'score': 0.00037431108648888767},
  {'label': 'embarrassment', 'score': 0.003977356944233179},
  {'label': 'excitement', 'score': 0.0005221295286901295},
  {'label': 'fear', 'score': 0.00013622187543660402},
  {'label': 'gratitude', 'score': 0.020833879709243774},
  {'label': 'grief', 'score': 0.0003116711159236729},
  {'label': 'joy', 'score': 0.0010206002043560147},
  {'label': 'love', 'score': 0.00041145001887343824},
  {'label': 'nervousness', 'score': 0.00014432560419663787},
  {'label': 'optimism', 'score': 0.0007541821687482297},
  {'label': 'pride', 'score': 0.00015070308290887624},
  {'label': 'realization', 'score': 0.019403191283345222},
  {'label': 'relief', 'score': 0.0006177137838676572},
  {'label': 'remorse', 'score': 0.7496775388717651},
  {'label': 'sadness', 'score': 0.0218233410269022},
  {'label': 'surprise', 'score': 0.0001970023731701076},
  {'label': 'neutral', 'score': 0.0070171356201171875}]]
```

Comment: it's another question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32946062)

Comment: You should try this: _sorted(emotion_labels[0], key=lambda x: x['score'])_